# In Mongoose (node.js MongoDB), how do I perform this update?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

```
{ 
   _id: 'abc123',
   reports: [ 
             { uid: 33, name: 'john' }, 
             { uid: 215, name: 'jess' },
             { uid: 29, name: 'hal'}
           ]
}
```

Let's say I have the document above.

```
models.Stuff.findOne({_id:'abc123'},function(err,result){
     //Got the above record.
});
```

After I get the document, how do I change all the "uids" to 0?  I want to go through all of the document's reports and change all the uids to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i in result.reports){
    result.reports[i].uid = 0;
}
result.save();
```

Comment: There might also be a way to do this with an `update()` using `$set`, although on an embedded document I'm not 100% sure how that would work.

Comment: Because `reports` is an "array of objects" the `$set` notation is unreliable (you have to update specific array indices). Of course, in the example above you have to recognize that you may be hammering someone's changes. (maybe they did a `$push` while you were changing `uid`) Depending on your use case, there's definitely space for data contention here.

Answer (score 0):

Better you use [pinch.min.js](https://github.com/Baggz/Pinch) which is very handy for this kind of requirement.